# Is it possible to get Siri to start a conversation?

Tags: ios, siri

From what I know of the SiriKit documentation, everything requires the user to invoke Siri and imitate a conversation (albeit a short one).

Is it possible when writing your own app, to use events such as arriving at home (location) to trigger Siri to say “Welcome home!”? This can be followed with Siri waiting for any sort of acknowledgement, and then offering HomeKit related actions - “now that we’re back, wanna fire up the console?”.

I recognise the issues that may arise with this - the user may not be alone, or may be engaged in something else, etc. but in combination with the X’s attention awareness - it might work.

Comment: I mean maybe you could have the voice of Siri read out some text, maybe that works.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth - right... so I could programmatically have Siri read out text based on location provided I had access, and use the user’s verbal response as an intent?

Answer (score 1):

No, such thing is not possible.

You cannot programatically invoke Siri, since you cannot even directly interact with Siri from an app, only using Intents Extensions. Only the user can start the interaction with Siri. Intents Extensions are invoked automatically by Siri when the user makes a prompt which can be executed by your app's Intents Extension.

Comment: So in every case, the user has to invoke siri first, and then ask for something from our app? Would it be possible to get siri to go through a series of events (calendar read outs, reminders, todos, etc.) by tapping a button? Instead of saying “hey Siri, what’s my day looking like?” <- assuming that’s the functionality we’re building here.

Comment: Yes, the user has to invoke Siri in every case and no, it is not possible to invoke Siri using a button inside your app or anything else but the default shortcuts (such as holding the home button or saying "Hey Siri").